# Scaling External Asymptote File within the Current Document

Tags: diagrams, scaling, external-files, asymptote

I have diagrams generated in Asymptote stored in external files. Is it possible to input the files into my current LaTeX document and to choose the scale factor within the current document?

The following naive approach does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}

A unit sphere, 1/4 size:
\begin{asy}[width=0.25\textwidth]
\input{asyfile}
\end{asy} 

\end{document}
```

Contents of asyfile:

```
import solids;
draw(unitsphere,gray);
```

(I use these diagrams in different contexts, so I do not want to pick the scaling within the Asymptote file.)

Comment: Don't use `TeX` `\input` command inside the `asy` environment,
instead of `\input{asyfile}` use the `Asymptote` code
`include asyfile;`

Comment: I've wondered the same thing. When I need to do this, I usually just compile the image separately and use `includegraphics` (no need for the `asymptote` package). You could make your `asy` environment consist of something like `size(5cm, 0); include asyfile;` which would set the sizing separately each time, but you can't use the `\textwidth` macro this way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is tempting to use the `TeX` commands
inside the `asy` environment, but it would result in a syntax error.
Inside the `Asymptote` code `TeX` commands 
are allowed and useful only surrounded by string delimiters
for example, in a `label` or `texpreamble` command,
so don't use `TeX` `\input` command inside the `asy` environment,
instead of `\input{asyfile}` use the `Asymptote` code
`include asyfile;` to include the external `.asy` file.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}

A unit sphere, 1/4 size:
\begin{asy}[width=0.25\textwidth]
include asyfile; // but not `\input{asyfile}` 
\end{asy} 

\end{document}
```