# trying to \input an asymptote-file

Tags: asymptote

Doing my first steps with Asymptote (seems to be a great tool) I ran into
the following problem. I usually try to put my graphics (tikz) into separate
files to be more flexible. So I would like to handle the asy-graphics as well.
But, the `\ASYinput` macro leads to the error message `! File ended while scanning use of \next`. Is there any (simple) way to get this running?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\newcommand{\ASYinput}[1]{%
   \begin{asy}
    \input{#1.asy}
   \end{asy}
}

\newcommand{\ASYinputx}[1]{%
    \input{#1.asy}
}

\begin{document}
blabla

\ASYinputx{test1}

blabla

\ASYinput{test2}

blabla
\end{document}
```

Here are the two test files.

```
// test2.asy
 size(10cm);
 draw((0,0)--(2,1));
```

and

```
// test1.asy
\begin{asy}
 size(10cm);
 draw((0,0)--(2,1));
\end{asy}
```

Comment: Only now I see that there is a dedicated command in `asymptote` package, see Christian Hupfer's answer. I think you should accept his answer instead of mine.

Comment: I am sorry, but I can't see Christian Hupfer on this thread.

Comment: Ops, I meant Charles Staats...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation for the `asymptote` package:

> If you have Asymptote code in a separate file, you can include it with
>   the `\asyinclude[options]{filename}` command.

Comment: Oups, I have to read again the doc...

Answer (score 4):

As indicated in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140090/101651), you can't use a TeX command (`\input`) inside the `asy` environment; you have to use the `asymptote` command `include`.

Moreover, as indicated in [this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/127021/101651), you can't hide the `asy` environment in a macro (but, of course, egreg found a solution).

Putting all this together, here's a working code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\asycode}[2][]{%
    \stepcounter{asy}%
    \setkeys{ASYkeys}{#1}%
    \ifASYattach
    \ASYinlinefalse
    \fi
    \ifx\asydir\empty\else
    \def\ASYprefix{\asydir/}%
    \fi
    \immediate\write\AsyPreStream{%
        \noexpand\InputIfFileExists{%
            \ASYprefix\noexpand\jobname-\the\c@asy.pre}{}{}%
    }
    \asy@write@graphic@header
    \immediate\write\AsyStream{\detokenize{#2}}% here asy does the writing
    \asy@finalise@stream
    \asy@input@graphic
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\ASYinput}[1]{%
    \asycode{include #1;}
}

\newcommand{\ASYinputx}[1]{%
\input{#1.asy}
}

\begin{document}

blabla

\ASYinputx{test1}

blabla

\ASYinput{test2}

blabla
\end{document}
```

With `test1.asy`:

```
\begin{asy}
 size(10cm);
 draw((0,0)--(2,1));
\end{asy}
```

and `test2.asy`:

```
size(10cm);
draw((0,0)--(2,1));
```

In this case, you can't use `filecontents` because it adds an empty line at the and of the file which is not accepted by `asymptote`.

If you want a piece of advice, [use `tikz`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39577/101651)!

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot for this thorough answer. Although I do not understand every step of the new macro, I will use it. Of course. -- Regarding your advice, which is surely welcome: I use TikZ for more than ten years and have about a thousand  graphs in my presentations, lecture notes and so on. But, I haven't been successful in creating 'fine' 3-D-pictures of antenna diagrams, mainly due to numerical constraints (even with pgfplots). So I will give Asymptote a try.

Comment: This behavior (not possible to hide macro inside an environment without a true macro like the egreg one) is due to the fact that `asy` is based on the `comments` environment. `asy` has the same limitations.

Comment: @Jürgen You're welcome, but for the macro you have to thank egreg! See also what O.G. has just written...

Comment: @O.G. Thank you for the explanation! I prefer TikZ even for the mere fact that you do not have to compile in 3 times...

Comment: @CarLaTeX We have the choice for graphics solutions... It is also possible to simply use `\includegraphics` and an appropriate `Makefile` for a complex process. Or `asypictureb`...

Comment: @O.G. Surely! I have only simple graphics to do, hence for me TikZ is more convenient, I imagine that for more complex ones Asymptote is indispensable...